# Show "Sold Out" if all the returned rows are equal to "Sold Out"

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query which looks up fares for each cabin category from a table called fares.

Each row has a field called status, which can be 'Available', 'Last Few' or 'Sold Out'

My query is like this...

```
$query_fares = sprintf("SELECT *, fares.fare-fares.offered AS yousave FROM cruises, fares WHERE fares.cruise_id = %s AND cruises.id = fares.cruise_id ORDER BY fares.sortorder ASC", GetSQLValueString($colname_fares, "text"));
```

IF all the the cabins are sold out, I want to display that they are. My code at the minute shows the words 'Sold Out' if the first record in the returned rows status is 'Sold out' which is no good. I only want to shows Sold Out if all the rows status's are Sold out.

MY current code is

```
<?php if($row_fares['status'] !== 'Sold Out') { echo "Prices from £" . $row_lowfare['MIN(offered)'] . ""; } ?>
```

What do I need to do to check that all returned rows status are = 'Sold Out'

Many thanks

Rich :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[mysql_fetch_array](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlfetcharray.php) would help , and then in the loop do a

`if($row_fares['status'] != 'Sold Out') { break; return false; }`

The return false can be used in a function.